# How to select only the first group of results, after custom sorting?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a hypothetical "items" table, the "type" values have an application-defined
priority (order): B before C before A. This priority is not part of the
database and can change between queries.

```
 id | owner_id | type |   name
----+----------+------+----------
  1 |        1 | A    | a item 1
  2 |        1 | A    | a item 2
  3 |        1 | B    | b item 1
  4 |        1 | B    | b item 2
  5 |        1 | C    | c item 1
  6 |        1 | C    | c item 2
  7 |        1 | D    | d item 1
  8 |        2 | A    | a item 3
  9 |        2 | C    | c item 3
```

I can get a list for one item owner, sorted by type priority:

```
 id | type |   name
----+------+----------
  3 | B    | b item 1
  4 | B    | b item 2
  5 | C    | c item 1
  6 | C    | c item 2
  1 | A    | a item 1
  2 | A    | a item 2
```

SQL:

```
  SELECT  id,
          type,
          name
    FROM  items
   WHERE  owner_id = 1
          AND type IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
ORDER BY  type != 'B',
          type != 'C',
          type != 'A',
          name;
```

Now I would like to select only the first group of types (the two B items). If
there are no B items, I want all the C items, and so on.

I could use a separate query or a self-join or a CTE to find the top type,
but I was wondering if there is a simpler or more elegant way to get only the
first group of results, after `ORDER BY` has been applied.

For example, if I could rank the groups, I could just select the rank 1 from
an outer query, but I can't seem to get the partitioning/ranking right. When
I select

```
dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY type)
```

all values for `dense_rank()` are 1.

Comment: RANK rather than DENSE_RANK, and ORDER BY rather than PARTITION BY...  `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE type WHEN 'b' THEN 0 WHEN 'c' THEN 1 WHEN 'a' THEN 2 END) AS ranked_type` with `WHERE ranked_type = 1`

Comment: That's it, thank you! If you want to put this as an answer, I will check it as the solution.